# Displaying class variables. Using string as parameter in printf function.

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how classes work, but I'm having a bit of trouble

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Student.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
Student students;

students.Print();

system("pause");

}
```

Student.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(void);
    ~Student(void);
    void Print(void);
private:
    int IDone;
    int IDtwo;
    string studentOne;
    string studentTwo;
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student(void)
{
    studentOne = "John Doe";
    studentTwo = "Jane Doe";
    IDone = 227768;
    IDtwo = 227769;
}

Student::~Student(void)
{
}
void Student::Print(void)
{
    printf("Student name: %s\n", studentOne);
    printf("Student ID: %d\n", IDone);
    printf("Student name: %s\n", studentTwo);
    printf("Student ID: %d\n", IDtwo);

}
```

When this runs I get:

```
    Student name: <null>
    Student ID: 227768
    Student name: <null>
    Student ID: 227769
```

Later I want to be able to change the names and IDs. Also, it is possible to have these member in a type of array so I could print it by going student[0] and student[1]?

Comment: Adding a homework tag to this. Please remove it if it's not applicable.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: A small side note: The design of the `Student` class seems... wrong. Mostly because it's maybe should be named `Students` since it contains information about two students. `Student` (singular) implies a single student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a reference about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and you will find a method named [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) that is used to get a C-style character pointer usable in e.g. `printf`.

Or just start using `std::cout` instead:

```
void Student::Print(void)
{
    std::cout << "Student name: " << studentOne << '\n';
    std::cout << "Student ID: " << IDone << '\n';
    std::cout << "Student name: " << studentTwo << '\n';
    std::cout << "Student ID: " << IDtwo << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use stl containers like [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead of arrays to store your student detail and you should remodel your student class to something like this

```
class Student
{
private:
 string Name;
 int    Id;
public:
 Student(string name, int id);
 string GetName();
 void SetName(name);
 int GetId();
 void SetId(int id);
 void Print();
};
```

and your main should be like this

```
   void main()
    {
      vector<Student> studentList;

      Studen one("John Doe", 1);
      Studen two("Jane Doe", 2);

      studentList.push_back(one);
      studentList.push_back(two);

      vector<Student>::const_iterator cii;
      for(cii=Student.begin(); cii!=Student.end(); cii++)
       {
          *cii.Print();

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Student name: %s\n", studentOne);
```

Results in undefined behavior. You need to pass a c style string which suits the `%s` format specifier, i.e. `studentOne.c_str()`.

> it is possible to have these member in a type of array so I could
>   print it by going student[0] and student[1]

You can always declare an array of `std::string` as any other data type.

```
class Student
{
  ...
  string students[N];  // or vector<string> students;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Student name: %s\n", studentOne);
```

You can't pass a C++ `std::string` to the C `printf` function; you can only pass the basic types that are shared with the C language; passing a class type will cause undefined behaviour.

You could use C++ output:

```
std::cout << "Student name: " << studentOne << std::endl;
```

or, if you really want to use C ouput for some reason, you could extract a C-style string from the `std::string`:

```
printf("Student name: %s\n", studentOne.c_str());
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

> Also, it is possible to have these member in a type of array so I could print it by going student[0] and student[1]?

Yes, you can put most types, including classes, in an array:

```
std::string student[2]; // array of two strings.
```

If you want a variable number, use a dynamic array:

```
std::vector<std::string> student;
```

It seems a bit odd for a single `Student` to have two names and two IDs, though. Shouldn't that class just represent one person?

Answer (score 0):

> Also, it is possible to have these member in a type of array so I could print it by going student[0] and student[1]?

Sure. If you know number of students upfront, then you can just:

```
string students[2];
```

This statement will effectively allocate two `string` objects in memory and you can reference each of them by array index.

If you dont know how many students you would need, then the best is to use `std::vector` class, because it is preferred way of representing dynamic arrays in C++.

You placed studentOne, studentTwo, IDOne and IDTwo data members under private section of your class declaration. This means you are allowed to manipulate them directly only within `Student` class implementation. The approach that most of other programmers would expect you to follow is to create special getter and setter methods:

```
const std::string& studentOne() const {return studentOne;}
void setStudentOne(const std::string& aStudentOne) {studentOne = aStudentOne;}
```

and so on. Creating `setStudentOne` is especially useful when you want to have some side effect. Otherwise, you can have single method to access it:

```
std::string& getStudentOne() {return studentOne;}
```

Alternatively, exposing direct access to fields (i.e. relocating them to under public section) is not a *taboo*. Just remember, this is not what most people would expect to see.